How do I filter a Dataframe using pandas
i have a challenge for today. Filter a CSV file using pandas to get the same result of the next query:
SELECT *
     , CASE COALESCE(first_msg_courier , 'infinity')
          < COALESCE(first_msg_customer, 'infinity')
          WHEN true  THEN 'Courier'
          WHEN false THEN 'Customer'  -- ELSE null
       END AS first_msg_by
     , LEAST(first_msg_courier, first_msg_customer) AS conversation_start
FROM  (
   SELECT order_id
        , city_code
        , min(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Co') AS first_msg_courier
        , min(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Cu') AS first_msg_customer
        , max(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Co') AS last_msg_courier
        , max(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Cu') AS last_msg_customer
        , max(message_sent_time) - min(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Co') AS responsive_delay_courier
        , max(message_sent_time) - min(message_sent_time) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Cu') AS responsive_delay_customer
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Co') AS num_msg_courier
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE app_type = 'Cu') AS num_msg_customer        
   FROM  (
    SELECT ccc.order_id, 
           ord.city_code,
           left(ccc.sender_app_type, 2) AS app_type, 
           ccc.message_sent_time 
    FROM customer_courier_chat_messages ccc
    INNER JOIN "Orders" ord
        ON ccc.order_id = ord.order_id) c
   GROUP  BY order_id, city_code
   ) sub;


the CSV file to us as an example are:
customer_courier_chat_messages
sender_app_type,customer_id,from_id,to_id,chat_started_by_message,order_id,order_stage,courier_id,message_sent_time
Customer IOS,99,99,21,FALSE,555,PICKING_UP,21,9/8/22 8:02
Courier IOS,99,21,99,FALSE,555,ARRIVING,21,9/8/22 8:01
Customer IOS,99,99,21,FALSE,555,PICKING_UP,21,9/8/22 8:00
Courier Android,122,87,122,TRUE,38,ADDRESS_DELIVERY,87,9/8/22 7:55
Customer Android,43,43,75,FALSE,875,PICKING_UP,75,7/8/22 14:55
Courier Android,43,75,43,FALSE,875,ARRIVING,75,7/8/22 14:53
Customer Android,43,43,75,FALSE,875,PICKING_UP,75,7/8/22 14:51
Courier Android,43,75,43,TRUE,875,ADDRESS_DELIVERY,75,7/8/22 14:50
Customer IOS,23,23,21,FALSE,134,PICKING_UP,21,7/8/22 10:02
Courier IOS,23,21,23,FALSE,134,ARRIVING,21,7/8/22 10:01
Customer IOS,23,23,21,FALSE,134,PICKING_UP,21,7/8/22 10:00

orders.csv
order_id,city_code
38,BCN
134,OPO
555,BCN
875,VAL

i start coding doing this:
import pandas as pd

ccc = pd.read_csv('customer_courier_chat_messages.csv')
ord = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')


inner_tables = pd.merge(ccc, ord, on=['order_id'], how='inner')
inner_tables['app_type'] = inner_tables.sender_app_type.astype(str).str[:2]

filter_1 = inner_tables[['order_id', 'city_code', 'app_type', 'message_sent_time']]

print(filter_1)

cols = ['order_id', 'city_code']
grouped_df1 = filter_1.groupby(cols).size()

# filter_2 = filter_1.groupby('order_id', 'city_code')
print(grouped_df1)
print('\n')

cols = ['order_id', 'city_code', 'app_type']  # we also group the app_type to get the min and max of message_sent_time
grouped_df1 = filter_1.groupby(cols).agg({'message_sent_time': ['min', 'max']}).unstack('app_type')  # after aggregation, we unstack the app_type
grouped_df1.columns = grouped_df1.columns.map('_'.join)  # we join the multi-level columns
grouped_df1.rename(columns={
    'message_sent_time_min_Co': 'first_msg_courier', 
    'message_sent_time_max_Co': 'last_msg_courier',
    'message_sent_time_min_Cu': 'first_msg_customer', 
    'message_sent_time_max_Cu': 'last_msg_customer'}).reset_index()  # we rename the columns and reset the index

I tried to get the diferences between timestamp coulmns in two ways but i got the next error:
grouped_df1["responsive_delay_courier"] = grouped_df1["message_sent_time_max_Co"].shift(1) - grouped_df1["message_sent_time_min_Co"]
# grouped_df1["c"] = (grouped_df1.message_sent_time_max_Co - grouped_df1.message_sent_time_min_Co) / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')



And there is something else: How i will get the number of messeges per Order for customers or couriers
Can somebody help me with this?
Regards

cols = ['order_id', 'city_code', 'app_type']  # we also group the app_type to get the min and max of message_sent_time
grouped_df1 = filter_1.groupby(cols).agg({'message_sent_time': ['min', 'max']}).unstack('app_type')  # after aggregation, we unstack the app_type
grouped_df1.columns = grouped_df1.columns.map('_'.join)  # we join the multi-level columns
grouped_df1.rename(columns={
    'message_sent_time_min_Co': 'first_msg_courier', 
    'message_sent_time_max_Co': 'last_msg_courier',
    'message_sent_time_min_Cu': 'first_msg_customer', 
    'message_sent_time_max_Cu': 'last_msg_customer'}).reset_index()  # we rename the columns and reset the index


Thanks you so much. The question will be, how i aggregate another collumns with the differences on time between (message_sent_time_max_Co - message_sent_time_min_Co ) - i'll update my question using your answer

If you're not specifying for read_csv the field formatted as date, it will read it as string. try the parse_date=True in the read_csv function or use to_datetime function after reading the file. Regarding count, you can add 'count' to the list (together with 'min' and 'max'), don't forget to create the relevant keys and values to the columns rename dictionary
